# Why My custom TypeExcludeFilter does not work?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In my spring boot web project,  there is a property named 'processType' configurred in application.properties file, the enums of this property are 'web','worker' and 'service', I  build different docker services according to  processType value  using the same gitlab codes.   And I want to exclude all controllers from registering as spring beans when processType value is 'worker' and 'service'. Of course, when this property value is web,  all controller need registering into spring container as component to handle web requests. I don't want use @ConditionalOnProperty annotation cause too many controllers need be handled.

here is my code.

project main class

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCustomSwagger
@EnableAsync
@ImportResource({"classpath:dubbo.xml", "classpath:dubbo-consumer.xml"})
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories
@EnableCaching
@EnableApolloConfig
//@SpringBootConfiguration
//@EnableAutoConfiguration
//@ComponentScan(
//    value = "com.example.package.subpack",
//    excludeFilters = {
//      @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.CUSTOM, classes = TypeExcludeFilter.class),
//      @ComponentScan.Filter(
//          type = FilterType.CUSTOM,
//          classes = AutoConfigurationExcludeFilter.class),
//      @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.CUSTOM, classes = ControllerExcludeTypeFilter.class)
//    })
public class TaskServiceApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(TaskServiceApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Bean
  public RestTemplate restTemplate(ClientHttpRequestFactory factory) {
    return new RestTemplate(factory);
  }

  @Bean
  public ClientHttpRequestFactory simpleClientHttpRequestFactory() {
    SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
    factory.setConnectTimeout(15000);
    factory.setReadTimeout(15000);
    return factory;
  }
}
```

my custom TypeExcludeFilter:

```java
/**
 * 按理讲只要继承TypeExcludeFilter就能自动执行match逻辑，但是实际测试多次，都不执行本Filter的match内容。 本过滤器无需修改启动类的springboot注解
 *
 * <p>改用{@link ControllerExcludeTypeFilter}实现，该类需要改动springboot的注解。
 *
 * @author hebin
 * @date 2023/9/22 17:37
 */
@Slf4j
public class ControllerTypeExcludeFilter extends TypeExcludeFilter {

    private String processType;
    private BeanFactory beanFactory;
    private final String controllerPackage = "com.example.package.subpack.controller";
    private final String healthCheckController = "com.example.package.subpack.controller.health.HealthCheckController";

    @Override
    public boolean match(MetadataReader metadataReader, MetadataReaderFactory metadataReaderFactory) {
        log.info("controller exclude filter match");

        AnnotationMetadata annotationMetadata = metadataReader.getAnnotationMetadata();
        ClassMetadata classMetadata = metadataReader.getClassMetadata();
        String className = classMetadata.getClassName();

        Set<String> annotationTypes = annotationMetadata.getAnnotationTypes();
        String processType = getProcessType();
        log.info("current service process type is : {}", processType);
        if (!ProcessTypeConst.WEB.equals(processType)) {
            if (isControllerPackageClass(className) && !isHealthCheckControllerClass(className)) {
                log.info("class is normal Controller. className:{},annotationTypes:{}", className, annotationTypes);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean isControllerPackageClass(String className) {
        return className.startsWith(controllerPackage);
    }

    private boolean isHealthCheckControllerClass(String className) {
        return className.startsWith(healthCheckController);
    }

    public String getProcessType() {
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(processType)) {
            readProcessType();
        }
        return processType;
    }

    private void readProcessType() {
        ConfigurableEnvironment environment = beanFactory.getBean(ConfigurableEnvironment.class);
        processType = environment.getProperty(ProcessTypeConst.PROCESS_TYPE);
    }

    @Override
    public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return (obj != null) && (getClass() == obj.getClass());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return getClass().hashCode();
    }
}
```

in my mind, i just need extend TypeExcludeFilter, and it will work cause TypeExcludeFilter class will find all its sub class to do some filter logic. source codes are:

```java
public class TypeExcludeFilter implements TypeFilter, BeanFactoryAware {

    private BeanFactory beanFactory;

    private Collection<TypeExcludeFilter> delegates;

    @Override
    public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean match(MetadataReader metadataReader, MetadataReaderFactory metadataReaderFactory) throws IOException {
        if (this.beanFactory instanceof ListableBeanFactory && getClass() == TypeExcludeFilter.class) {
            for (TypeExcludeFilter delegate : getDelegates()) {
                if (delegate.match(metadataReader, metadataReaderFactory)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private Collection<TypeExcludeFilter> getDelegates() {
        Collection<TypeExcludeFilter> delegates = this.delegates;
        if (delegates == null) {
            delegates = ((ListableBeanFactory) this.beanFactory).getBeansOfType(TypeExcludeFilter.class).values();
            this.delegates = delegates;
        }
        return delegates;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("TypeExcludeFilter " + getClass() + " has not implemented equals");
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        throw new IllegalStateException("TypeExcludeFilter " + getClass() + " has not implemented hashCode");
    }

}
```

However, in fact, my custom Filter wont work expected. so why?

Finally I give up @SpringBootApplication annotation, and code as follows. it works well, but i still don't know why my custom TypeExcludeFilter does not work?

project main class

```java
//@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCustomSwagger
@EnableAsync
@ImportResource({"classpath:dubbo.xml", "classpath:dubbo-consumer.xml"})
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories
@EnableCaching
@EnableApolloConfig
@SpringBootConfiguration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(value = "com.example.package.subpack", excludeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.CUSTOM, classes = TypeExcludeFilter.class), @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.CUSTOM, classes = AutoConfigurationExcludeFilter.class), @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.CUSTOM, classes = ControllerExcludeTypeFilter.class)})
public class TaskServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TaskServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(ClientHttpRequestFactory factory) {
        return new RestTemplate(factory);
    }

    @Bean
    public ClientHttpRequestFactory simpleClientHttpRequestFactory() {
        SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
        factory.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        factory.setReadTimeout(15000);
        return factory;
    }
}
```

My own FilterType:

```java
/**
 * 该类需要改动springboot的注解。删掉@SpringBootApplication，改用其内三个注解，其中ComponentScan注解增加本过滤器
 *
 * @date 2023/9/22 17:37
 */
@Slf4j
public class ControllerExcludeTypeFilter implements TypeFilter, BeanFactoryAware {

    private String processType;
    private BeanFactory beanFactory;
    private static final String controllerAnnotationName = Controller.class.getName();

    private final String healthCheckController = "com.example.package.subpack.controller.health.HealthCheckController";

    @Override
    public boolean match(MetadataReader metadataReader, MetadataReaderFactory metadataReaderFactory) {
        String processType = getProcessType();
        if (ProcessTypeConst.WEB.equals(processType)) {
            return false;
        }

        AnnotationMetadata annotationMetadata = metadataReader.getAnnotationMetadata();
        if (!annotationMetadata.isAnnotated(controllerAnnotationName)) {
            return false;
        }

        String className = metadataReader.getClassMetadata().getClassName();
        if (isHealthCheckControllerClass(className)) {
            return false;
        }

        log.info("class is normal Controller and will not be registered into spring container.processType:{}, className:{}", processType, className);
        return true;

    }

    private boolean isHealthCheckControllerClass(String className) {
        return className.startsWith(healthCheckController);
    }

    public String getProcessType() {
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(processType)) {
            readProcessType();
        }
        return processType;
    }

    private void readProcessType() {
        ConfigurableEnvironment environment = beanFactory.getBean(ConfigurableEnvironment.class);
        processType = environment.getProperty(ProcessTypeConst.PROCESS_TYPE);
        log.info("controller exclude type filter has read process type property. processType:{}", processType);
    }

    @Override
    public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
    }
}
```